# Find $\frac{1}{\log 2}+\frac{1}{(\log 2)(\log 3)}+\frac{1}{(\log 2)(\log 3)(\log 4)}+ \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

Is it possible to calculate the sum of $\dfrac{1}{\log 2}+\dfrac{1}{(\log 2)(\log 3)}+\dfrac{1}{(\log 2)(\log 3)(\log 4)}+ \cdots$?

Comment: You mean does it converge, don't you?

Comment: ^It is possible he wants to if there is a closed form. It seems to converge to roughly $4.93427....$

Comment: How find this sum without the use of programs?

Comment: Computing it shows a very fast convergence. Using $15$ terms already gives $4.93419$; $20$ terms lead to the value given by JimmyK4542. Now, is there a closed form ?

Comment: Series is infinite

Comment: This is probably just a coincidence, but it's awfully close to $\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}$... (awfully meaning up to the first three digits after the decimal point)

Comment: You should prove the convergence of the series.

Comment: Series of this form always have a continued fraction expansion by Euler's continued fraction formula, which converges very quickly and with good accuracy; see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula.  But for a closed form formula: the ubiquity of these series shows in fact that one should not expect a closed form simply because of the format $a_0+a_0a_1+\cdots$ and if this is so, I do not see what specific propetry of the logarithm would make the difference in this special case.  Maybe the recurrence formula for the convergents can give something non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Convergence is easily proven since the series can be written as $$\begin{align*} S &= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \biggl( \prod_{j=2}^k \log j \biggr)^{-1} \\ &= (\log 2)^{-1} \left( 1 + \sum_{k=3}^\infty \biggl( \prod_{j=3}^k \log j \biggr)^{-1} \right) \\ &< (\log 2)^{-1} \left( 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\log 3)^{-k}\right) \\ &= \frac{\log 3}{\log 2(\log 3 - 1)}.\end{align*}$$  A closed form value is substantially more difficult to obtain but I will leave this as an establishment of convergence.

Comment: Does your last comment imply that a closed form is known?

Comment: @guest  No.  I am only stating that should such a closed form exist, obtaining it is very likely to be much more difficult than something as simple as what I wrote for convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: let 
$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\log x}+\dfrac{1}{(\log x)(\log (x+1))}+\dfrac{1}{(\log x)(\log (x+1))(\log (x+2))}+ \cdots$$
then 
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\dfrac{1}{\log x}+\dfrac{1}{(\log x)(\log (x+1))}+\dfrac{1}{(\log x)(\log (x+1))(\log (x+2))}+ \cdots\\
f(x)&=\dfrac{1}{\log x}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{(\log (x+1))}+\dfrac{1}{(\log (x+1))(\log (x+2))}+ \cdots\right)\\
f(x)&= \frac{1+f(x+1)}{\log(x)}\\
\implies f(x+1)&=\log(x) f(x)-1
\end{align}
$$
So we now have a recurrence relation for the function, and we are seeking $f(2)$. By repeatedly reducing $f(x+n+1)$, we also obtain
$$f(x+n)=\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\log(x+k)\right) f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\log(x+i)$$

So if we can come up with $f(x)$ for some integer $x$, we can come up with $f(x)$ for any integer $x$. I can't seem to come up with a value for anything though, so hopefully someone else can.